# perl invokes shell-- interrupt ^C stops the shell, not the perl

Tags: perl, shell, interrupt-handling

I want to use a Perl script to batch a repetitive operation which is invoked with system(). When something goes wrong and I want to interrupt this script, the ^C is captured by the shell, stopping whatever job, and the Perl script goes merrily along to the next one.

Is there a way I can invoke the job so that an interrupt will stop the Perl script?

Answer (score 9):

You can check `$?` to see whether the command executed by system died from signal 2 (`INT`):

Here's a full example of parsing `$?`:

```
my $rc=system("sleep 20"); 
my $q=$?; 
if ($q == -1) { 
    print "failed to execute: $!\n"
} elsif ($? & 127) { 
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",  
           ($q & 127), ($q & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
} else { 
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $q >> 8;
}
# Output when Ctrl-C is hit: 
# child died with signal 2, without coredump
```

Therefore the exact check you want is:

```
my $rc=system("sleep 20"); 
my $q=$?; 
if ($q != -1 &&  (($q & 127) == 2) && (!($? & 128))) { 
        # Drop the "$? & 128" if you want to include failures that generated coredump
    print "Child process was interrupted by Ctrl-C\n";
}
```

References: [perldoc system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for `$?` handling and `system()` call; [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more details on `$?`

Answer (score 5):

You are not checking the return value of `system`. Add to your parent program:

```
use autodie qw(:all);
```

and it program will abort as expected:

```
"…" died to signal "INT" (2) at … line …
```

You may catch this exception with [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny) in order to clean-up on your own or use a different message.